# Why does clicking a list element trigger an event on its parent element?

Tags: javascript, css, events

I am trying to implement a simplified version of a collapsible multi level/nested list based [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp), see below. Clicking on list item `id="li1"` causes first descendant `UL` element `id="ul1"` to open as expected. When list item `id="li4"` is clicked, the first descendant `UL` element `id="ul2"` is opened as expected but why is then `UL` element `id="ul1"` closed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Collapsible multi-level list</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
      /* Remove default bullets */
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      /* Style the caret/arrow */
      .caret {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none; /* Prevent text selection */
      }
      /* Create the caret/arrow with a unicode, and style it */
      .caret::before {
        content: "\25B6";
        color: black;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 6px;
      }
      /* Rotate the caret/arrow icon when clicked on (using JavaScript) */
      .caret-down::before {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
      /* Hide the nested list */
      .init-closed {
        display: none;
      }
      /* Show the nested list when the user clicks on the caret/arrow (with JavaScript) */
      .open {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ml-list">
      <ul class="open">
        <li class="caret" id="li1">listItem 1
          <ul class="init-closed" id="ul1">
            <li>listItem 2</li>
            <li>listItem 3</li>
            <li class="caret" id="li4">listItem 4
              <ul class="init-closed" id="ul2">
                <li>listItem 5</li>
                <li>listItem 6</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>listItem 7</li>
            <li class="caret" id="li8">listItem 8
              <ul class="init-closed" id="ul3">
                <li>listItem 9</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      const toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
      console.log(toggler);
      const toggle = (ind) => {
        console.log(ind, toggler[ind].getAttribute("id"));
        toggler[ind].querySelector("UL").classList.toggle("open");
        toggler[ind].classList.toggle("caret-down");
      };
      for (let i = 0; i < toggler.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(i, toggler[i]);
        toggler[i].addEventListener("click", () => toggle(i));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason is [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#bubbling).

Comment: @Mushroomator thanks for the quick answer, I had never heard event bubbling. I managed to stop it by adjusting the `toggle` function expression to include `ev.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to check what the event target was (ie use event.target). Then only invoke your handler function (toggle()) if the event.target was what you wanted it to be. You could check for the value of some attribute on the event.target. You have to pass the event in to your function

I am not too good at arrow functions so I do it like this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (event.target === "li") {
        toggle(i);
    }
});
```

I have also seen `event.target.closest("li")`

This is a good approach to make your event handler to only respond to the exact thing the user clicked on. You can have several different responses for different actions that the user took.

Note that you can use any word in place of event. A lot of people use `e`